# Provisioning MariaDB on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mysql, mariadb, vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-provision

I can automatically setup and set MariaDB 10.0 root password on my previous vagrant box using Ubuntu 18.04 with this in my provision file

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password root'
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password root'
sudo apt-get install -y mysql-server
```

But it doesn't work on Ubuntu 20.04 and MariaDB 10.3. I tried testing by installing it manually, and apparently the installation now doesn't prompt for default password for root user.

Is there any other way to setup root password automatically as I am only using this box for development environment?

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple solution. Apparently the password does work, but only if the MySQL console is accessed from the box itself. I just need to add new root user through MySQL console command. Here is what my provision file look now

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password root'
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password root'
sudo apt-get install -y mysql-server

mysql -u root -proot -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'root' WITH GRANT OPTION;"
mysql -u root -proot -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'root' WITH GRANT OPTION;"
mysql -u root -proot -e "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
```